# Computing an approximate value of Pi via Monte Carlo method in Java with streams

Tags: java, numerical-methods

I have this short program that attempts to compute an approximate value of \$\pi\$:

```
package net.coderodde.fun;

import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

/**
 * This class computes an approximate value of Pi. 
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Feb 23, 2018)
 */
public class MonteCarloPiComputer {

    /**
     * The default radius of the simulated circle.
     */
    private static final double DEFAULT_RADIUS = 0.5;

    /**
     * The random number generator.
     */
    private final Random random;

    public MonteCarloPiComputer(Random random) {
        this.random = 
                Objects.requireNonNull(
                        random, 
                        "The input random number generator is null.");
    }

    public MonteCarloPiComputer() {
        this(new Random());
    }

    /**
     * Computes an approximate value of Pi via a Monte Carlo method. The method
     * creates {@code samples} random points, computes the percentage of all 
     * points within the radius from the center of the simulated square and 
     * multiplies it by {@code 4.0}.
     * 
     * @param samples the number of points to create.
     * @param radius  the radius of the simulated circle.
     * @return an approximate value of Pi.
     */
    public double computeApproximateValueOfPi(int samples, double radius) {
        Point2D.Double center = new Point2D.Double(radius, radius);
        double squareSideLength = 2.0 * radius;
        long numberOfPointsWithinCircle = 
            IntStream.range(0, samples)
                     .mapToObj(
                             (i) -> { 
                                 return new Point2D.Double(
                                         squareSideLength * random.nextDouble(),
                                         squareSideLength * random.nextDouble()); 
                             })
                     .filter((point) -> { 
                         return point.distance(center) < radius; 
                     }).count();

        return (4.0 * numberOfPointsWithinCircle) / samples;
    }

    /**
     * Computes an approximate value of Pi via a Monte Carlo method with default
     * radius.
     * 
     * @param samples the number of points to create.
     * @return an approximate value of Pi.
     */
    public double computeApproximateValueOfPi(int samples) {
        return computeApproximateValueOfPi(samples, DEFAULT_RADIUS);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MonteCarloPiComputer computer = new MonteCarloPiComputer();

        for (int samples = 100_000; samples <= 1_000_000; samples += 100_000) {
            double approximation = 
                    computer.computeApproximateValueOfPi(samples);
            double percentage = approximation / Math.PI;
            System.out.print(String.format("%7d: ", samples));
            System.out.print(String.format("%10f", approximation));
            System.out.println(
                    String.format(
                            ", percentage from exact Pi: %10f", 
                            (100.0 * percentage)));
        }
    }
}
```

## Critique request

I would like to hear any comments and improvement suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some superfluous `import`s.  I also think that you can rename `computeApproximateValueOfPi()` to `approximatePi()` without losing any clarity.

The simulation is complicated by the fact that the circle is centered at an adjustable point `(radius, radius)`.  You could just as easily use a unit circle centered at the origin, and generate points in a square with *x* in the range [0, 1) and *y* in the range [0, 1).  The computation is mathematically equivalent, with less shifting and scaling.

Furthermore, there is no need to instantiate a `Point2D` for each generated point.  You can use [`.distance(x, y)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.html#distance-double-double-).  Better yet, avoid computing the square root by using [`.distanceSq(x, y)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.html#distanceSq-double-double-).

The output routine in `main()` could be improved.  Your `percentage` variable doesn't actually store a percentage as its name suggests; the 100× happens in the formatting instead.  Splitting up the formatting into several `System.out.print()` calls defeats the purpose of `String.format()`.  I'd combine them all into one `System.out.format()` call.  Finally, the "percentage from" wording implies that you are calculating the difference; the calculation that you actually performed is what I would call "percentage of".

```
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class MonteCarloPiComputer {
    /**
     * The random number generator.
     */
    private final Random random;

    public MonteCarloPiComputer(Random random) {
        this.random = Objects.requireNonNull(
            random, 
            "The input random number generator is null."
        );
    }

    public MonteCarloPiComputer() {
        this(new Random());
    }

    /**
     * Computes an approximate value of Pi via a Monte Carlo method. The method
     * creates {@code samples} random points in the upper-right quadrant,
     * computes the fraction of all points within the radius from the origin
     * and multiplies it by {@code 4.0}.
     * 
     * @param samples the number of points to create.
     * @return an approximate value of Pi.
     */
    public double approximatePi(int samples) {
        Random r = this.random;
        Point2D.Double origin = new Point2D.Double();
        long pointsWithinUnitArc = IntStream.range(0, samples)
             .filter(i -> origin.distanceSq(r.nextDouble(), r.nextDouble()) < 1)
             .count();
        return (4.0 * pointsWithinUnitArc) / samples;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MonteCarloPiComputer computer = new MonteCarloPiComputer();

        for (int samples = 100_000; samples <= 1_000_000; samples += 100_000) {
            double approximation = computer.approximatePi(samples);
            double pctDiff = 100 * (approximation - Math.PI) / Math.PI;
            System.out.format("%7d: %10f, deviation from exact Pi: %+10f%%%n",
                samples,
                approximation,
                pctDiff
            );
        }
    }
}
```